# Resetting a Liquid Variable in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I needed to make two seperate slideshows in shopify, one for mobile and one for desktop. This is an oversimplified example but what I do not understand is why the variable `image_position` is not reset to `0`. This should be simple, but coming from javascript, I have no idea what could cause this not to work, and I also have a limited understanding whether liquid even implements some kind of scope.

```html
<!-- Capture desktop images -->
{%- capture desk_slideshow_images -%}
  {%- for image in product.images -%}
    <div class="desktop__image" data-image-index="{% increment image_position %}">
          <img src="{{ image | img_url: 'x1600' }}">
    </div>
  {%- endfor -%}
{%- endcapture -%}

<!-- Try to reassign image_position variable to 0 -->
{% assign image_position = 0 %}


<!-- Capture mobile images -->
{%- capture mobile_slideshow_images -%}
  <!-- Another attempt to reassign image_position variable to 0 -->
  {% assign image_position = 0 %}

  {%- for image in product.images -%}
    <img class="mobile__image" src="{{ image | img_url: 'x1600' }}" data-image-index="{% increment image_position %}">
  {%- endfor -%}
{%- endcapture -%}
```

If there are three product images, on desktop the output is shown below. The `data-image-index` starts at `0` and increments as I would expect. But in the second block, it does not start counting from `0` again.

```html
<div class="desktop__image" data-image-index="0">
  <img src="...">
</div>
<div class="desktop__image" data-image-index="1">
  <img src="...">
</div>
<div class="desktop__image" data-image-index="2">
  <img src="...">
</div>
```

However, on mobile, it starts counting at `2` producing the following output:

```html
<img class="mobile__image" src="..." data-image-index="3">
<img class="mobile__image" src="..." data-image-index="4">
<img class="mobile__image" src="..." data-image-index="5">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Shopify’s documentation](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags/increment):

> Variables that are created with increment are independent from those created with assign and capture.

Instead of using `increment`, you could use an `assign` declaration again and increment the value there. Here’s an example based on your code:

```html
<!-- Capture desktop images -->
{%- capture desk_slideshow_images -%}
  {% assign image_position = 0 %}
  {%- for image in product.images -%}
    <div class="desktop__image" data-image-index="{{ image_position }}">
          <img src="{{ image | img_url: 'x1600' }}">
    </div>
    {% assign image_position = image_position + 1 %}
  {%- endfor -%}
{%- endcapture -%}

<!-- Capture mobile images -->
{%- capture mobile_slideshow_images -%}
  <!-- Another attempt to reassign image_position variable to 0 -->
  {% assign image_position = 0 %}
  {%- for image in product.images -%}
    <img class="mobile__image" src="{{ image | img_url: 'x1600' }}" data-image-index="{{ image_position }}">
    {% assign image_position = image_position + 1 %}
  {%- endfor -%}
{%- endcapture -%}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that. I was looking at assign the whole time. The next site I build will be with nuxt, working with liquid in shopify has not been a very enjoyable experience.